# Updating Scipy version to latest on Windows

Tags: python

I've never updated my Scipy version and would like to.  I'm running WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can upgrade scipy by running this in the windows command line

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and python says I've upgraded, but when I run scipy.__version__ I still see version 0.17.0.  Could you let me know what I need to do please?

Comment: Installing python packages on windows is a pain. Second method you can try is installing wheels from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: To do that, download the correct .whl file for your Python version to some location, e.g. D:\scipy\ and then launch the WinPython Command Prompt and type: pip install —no-index —upgrade D:\scipy\<name of wheel.whl>